# parse .sql file with comments into SQLite with python

Tags: python, sqlite

I have created a `.sql` file from a DIA diagram using the commandline tool `parsediasql.exe`

The resultant .sql file contains the commands and plenty of comments as well.

I created the following script to create the SQLIte database from the .sql definition file:

```
import sqlite3
import os
from unidecode import unidecode

def remove_non_ascii(text):
    return unidecode(unicode(text, encoding = "utf-8"))

def strip_non_ascii(string):
    ''' Returns the string without non ASCII characters'''
    stripped = (c for c in string if 0 < ord(c) < 127)
    return ''.join(stripped)

userhome = os.path.expanduser('~')
desktop = userhome + '\\Desktop\\'
#conn = sqlite3.connect(desktop + 'dbejemplo.db')
conn = sqlite3.connect('dbejemplo.db')
cursor = conn.cursor()

filename = '.\\Schematic\\code.sql'
with open(filename, 'r',  encoding="utf-8") as myfile:
    sqlcode = myfile.read().replace('\n', '')
orders = sqlcode.split(';')

for order in orders:
    try:
        sql = strip_non_ascii(order) + ';'
        cursor.execute(sql)
    except:
        print('Error:\n', sql)
```

This script works when I remove absolutely all the coments from the `.sql` file by hand.
**How can I remove the .sql comments using python? or How can I just send all the commands at once to SQLite interpreter?**

This SQL code should do for a test:

```sql
-- Arranques
create table startups (
   id        INTEGER      not null,
   Stage     INTEGER              ,--  Numero de la etapa (1 a 4)
   Seq_descr VARCHAR(256)         ,--  Descripcion de la secuencia
   Qfuel1    FLOAT                ,--  Valores de contador (kg) del combustible 1 (principal del motor)
   Qfuel2    FLOAT                ,--  Valores de contador (kg) del combustible 2
   Qfuel3    FLOAT                ,--  Valores de contador (kg) del combustible 3
   Qfuel4    FLOAT                ,--  Valores de contador (kg) del combustible 4
   Eaux      FLOAT                ,--  Valores de contador de energía activa de servicios auxiliares (kWh)
   Enet      FLOAT                ,--  Valores de contador de la energía neta activa  (kWh)
   constraint pk_startups primary key (id)
)   ;

create table companies (
   id   INTEGER      not null,
   name VARCHAR(256)         ,--  Nombre de la compañia
   constraint pk_companies primary key (id)
)   ;
```

Comment: Why do you want to remove the comments? Just execute the .sql file as is.

Comment: If I execute the code as is SQLite rejects it.

Comment: Comments should be ignored. What exactly does SQLite reject?

Comment: `sqlite3.OperationalError: near "--  Nombre de la compaia   constraint pk_companies primary key (id))   ;": syntax error`

Comment: What is the actual SQL statement that you tried to execute?

Comment: See the question, there are Python and sql code samples

Answer (score 0):

I've been through similar problem already.

This is what i came up with:

```
import re
import six
def remove_comments(string, specific_comment_re=None):
    # pattern = r"(\".*?\"|\'.*?\')|(/\*.*?\*/|(?:#|--\s)[^\n]*$)"
    if specific_comment_re:
        additional_patterns = "|"
        if isinstance(specific_comment_re, six.string_types):
            additional_patterns += specific_comment_re
        elif isinstance(specific_comment_re, list):
            additional_patterns += "|".join(specific_comment_re)
    pattern = r"(\".*?\"|\'.*?\')|(/\*.*?\*/{})".format(additional_patterns)
    # first group captures quoted strings (double or single)
    # second group captures comments (/* multi-line */ or
    # 'specific_comment_re')
    regex = re.compile(pattern, re.MULTILINE | re.DOTALL)

    def _replacer(match):
        # if the 2nd group (capturing comments) is not None,
        # it means we have captured a non-quoted (real) comment string.
        if match.group(2):
            return ""  # so we will return empty to remove the comment
        else:  # otherwise, we will return the 1st group
            return match.group(1)  # captured quoted-string
    return regex.sub(_replacer, string)

SQL_COMMENT_RE = {
    'oracle':
        [r'(?:--)[^\n]*\n', r'(?:\W|^)(?:remark|rem)\s+[^\n]*\n'],
    'mysql':
        [r'(?:#|--\s)[^\n]*\n']
}

def strip_sql_comments(sql_fn, db_type=None):
    """
    strips SQL comments in the 'sql_fn' file,
    returns stripped file content as a string
    """
    return remove_comments(
        my_common.get_file_contents(sql_fn, errors='ignore'),
        specific_comment_re=SQL_COMMENT_RE[db_type.lower()])
```

`my_common.get_file_contents` - is a wrapper-function which returns the file's contents - i needed it in order work around some broken UTF-8 encoded files

Or you can use [sqlparse.format()](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/sqlparse) function, but in my case it was very slow on big SQL files (10MiB+), so i had to find my own solution for that.

Comment: Hi the code misses the `re` and `six` variables in `remove_comments`

Answer (score 0):

```
sqlcode = myfile.read().replace('\n', '')
```

SQL comments are terminated by a newline.
So removing newlines will break all lines following a comment.

Just leave the newlines alone.

Using semicolons to detect the end of a statement does not work reliably because they can occur inside comments, strings, or trigger bodies.
Go through the data line by line, and call [complete_statement](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.complete_statement) to find out when you can execute it.

Answer (score 0):

This worked:

```
filename = 'code.sql'
lines = tuple(open(filename, 'r'))  # read the file line by line into array
sqlcode = ''
for line in lines:
    sqlcode += re.sub(r'--.*?\n', '', line + '\n')  # remove the in-line comments

orders = sqlcode.split(';') # split the text into commands

# Create the database and execute the commands
for order in orders:
    try:
        sql = strip_non_ascii(order) + ';'
        cursor.execute(sql)
    except:
        print('Error:\n', sql, '\n\n')
```